# How to set environment variable for AWS CDK with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cdk

I'd like to set an environment variable that's available in my Nodejs application that's deployed to Elastic Beanstalk using AWS CDK. I've tried to add it to the `Environment` options, but the deployment gets stuck for several minutes until I manually cancel the stack update.

Here's how I tried to add the environment variable, according to the [docs from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html):

```
      {
        namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment',
        optionName: 'CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN',
        value:
          'http://my-frontend.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
      }
```

I've also tried adding the value using '`http...`' and '"http..."' without success.

Here's the complete script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import ebs = require('@aws-cdk/aws-elasticbeanstalk');

export class MyPrototype extends cdk.Stack {
  public constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const appName = 'MyPrototypeApp';
    const platform = this.node.tryGetContext('platform');

    const app = new ebs.CfnApplication(this, 'Application', {
      applicationName: appName
    });

    const options: ebs.CfnEnvironment.OptionSettingProperty[] = [
      {
        namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration',
        optionName: 'IamInstanceProfile',
        value: 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role'
      },
      {
        namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs',
        optionName: 'NodeVersion',
        value: '10.15.0'
      },
      {
        namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment',
        optionName: 'CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN',
        value:
          'http://my-frontend.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
      }
    ];

    new ebs.CfnEnvironment(this, 'Environment', {
      environmentName: 'MyPrototypeEnvironment',
      applicationName: app.applicationName || appName,
      platformArn: platform,
      optionSettings: options
    });
  }
}

const app = new cdk.App();

new MyPrototype(app, 'ElasticBeanstalk');

app.synth();
```

Comment: no answers yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's failing because that's the way of setting env variables, inside the optionSettings, using 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment' as namespace (also you can add multiple namespaces with the same name)

Comment: `'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'` worked for me as well.